# How to find what pages/posts contain a particular reusable block?

Tags: wp-cli

How can I find out what pages and post on a site contain a particular reusable block?

Typically, to find content on a site, I issue `wp db search *itemlookingfor*` (like the post ID, part of a file name, or a word)

OR

`wp db query 'SELECT ID FROM the_posts_table WHERE post_content LIKE "%itemlookingfor%" AND post_status="publish"'`

In my case, I used the reusable block's ID and no results were returned for either command.
I replaced the ID of the reusable block with other common words on my site and results were returned so I think it's something special with reusable blocks.

Ideally, I'd like to use a wp-cli command or failing that, a sql command to search my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those commands do work now after I stepped away for a few hours from the problem; so it was something on my end.

In my examples in the question, You can substitute the reusable block's post_id with the `itemlookingfor` to obtain the pages that contain your reusable block.

Answer (score 0):

I can run `wp db query` for blocks I've created with ACF without issue. I assume this would work for any block ID. Eg:

```
wp db query 'select id, guid from wp_posts where post_content like "%acf/cta%" AND post_status!="inherit"'
```

You can also use the `search-replace` command in a sideways way to retrieve block content. Here's a method I used for finding the string "acf/cta" and printing it and the following 400 chars from the found string to a log file (I was trying to get block options).

```
wp search-replace "acf/cta" "whatever" --dry-run --log --before_context=0 --after_context=400 > cta.log
```